# I'm trying to make a program to lock a website, but I can't get it to work

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to make a program in javascript that will lock a site. All that you'll have to do is type it into the console in chrome dev tools, and an alert will pop up asking for a password. If the password is correct, it will get rid of the alert. If the password is incorrect, the alert will pop up again. The alert popping up part is working correct, but even when the password is correct, the alert pops up again.

```
function firstFunction() {
var psswrd = prompt("What is the password?")
}
function mainFunction() {
  var done = "two"
  var psswrd = "johndoe"
  while ("two"==done) {
    firstFunction()
    if (psswrd == "password") {
      var done = "one"
    }
  }
}
mainFunction()
```

Comment: Hi Aidan, have a read on variable scope - that *may* be the source of your problem

Comment: @AIDAN GREEN checkout my answer, maybe it will help you out :)

Comment: To diagnose problems like this, debug and check that the variable values are what you expect, or you can debug old school style by throwing up an alert with the current value of psswrd just before you check it against "password"  to see if it is what you expect

Comment: It will be more helpful long term to understand exactly *why* the suggested solutions work. I'm sure you wouldn't just copy them without thinking through what is different about your original approach :-)

Comment: @Chris the only thing different I could find with the suggested solutions is that they do not use a function within a function, and (in the case of Sowam's awnser) that they assign the variable psswrd (or prmptValue) is given a value of null before the prompt. However, I don't see how the assigning value of null is any different from assigning it a value of 'john doe' because neither is the correct password.

Comment: Hi, I think you are right about null, it's the function I think - that's what I mean about variable scope - do read up and/or debug through your code to see what is going on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function mainFunction() {
  const correctPass = "correct";

  let promptValue = null;

  while (promptValue !== correctPass) {
      promptValue = prompt("What is the password?")
  }
}

mainFunction()
```

to explain:

- first of all I setup correct value
- I set promtValue to null because in the beggining it has to be null to be able to run first line of `while`
- then I change it to the answer from prompt and when user types correct password it will just not go through `while (promptValue !== correctPass)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
function mainFunction() {
  var done = "two"
  
  while ("two"==done) {
    var psswrd = prompt("Whats the word")
    if (psswrd == "password") {
      var done = "one"
    }
  }
}
mainFunction()
```

Comment: This does seem to work, but it doesn't explain how it works. Is it just because that it no longer uses a function within a function?

Comment: It has to variable scope. The local variable psswrd inside the mainFunction of your code is never updated. Calling firstFunction does update psswrd, it simply declares a new local variable with the same name, writes the prompt data to it, and then discards it.

To do it your way, you would have to declare psswrd as a global variable or pass the one declared inside mainFunction to firstFunction and then make firstFunction return it.

Hope that makes sense